# How do I make my search bar search for my other pages

Tags: html

Made a search bar for my website but I don't actually know how to make it search for other pages.
Here is the code:

```
<!-- Search Box -->
        <div class="search-box">
            <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Search..">

            <a class="search-btn" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                
            </a>
<!--// Search Box -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to perform search is not implemented in the code you had pasted. Ideally the below line in your HTML markup

```
<a class="search-btn" href="#">
```

should point to a search action with parameters to search picked from the input field you had specified as below, probably through a javascript.

```
<input class="search-txt" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Search..">
```

Or else, the input field itself should be within a form, whose action should point to a server method/function that takes what is typed in the input field either through a GET or POST, based on form action method you would have specified like something below.

```
<form id='searchbox' action='search' method='GET'>
       <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Search..">
        <button class="search-btn" type='submit'>
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
</form>
```

If you do not have any such thing in place, you can try adding a Google custom search to your page, which is described in the below article.This can be used if your search is only in the page content and not anything in your database.

[Wikihow - How to add a google search bar](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Google-Search-Bar-to-Your-Website)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a search bar to the website is not going to do it.

You will have to send the search query for some server side processing (Example PHP) and that script will be the one doing the searching and outputting search results dynamically based on the search query.

Therefore you need:

1. Form data to be submitted.
2. Server side handling/processing of that submitted data.
3. Take user to the output page of that search results.